# SQL: how to count total of one column if one other column is there?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Edit: it seems I have not explained well enough. I will try again

I would like to return this. If `app_type` equals "software update" then add up the values of `bytes_received` and `bytes_sent`.

```
app_type          Bytes_received  Bytes_sent
------------------------------------------------
software updates  10098120398214  09832140914
email              89032409       9874398
```

The first of below queries return and counts all the times that app_type in in the data. its a big table with 700000 entries

The second shows how much `bytes_received` is being used for the entry 'software updates'

end edit.

I have a table called `WirelessAppData` and I am trying to find work out the add up the amount of traffic being used sent and received for the data in the `app_type` column. I have added the things I have tried.

I really would like to return a table from highest to lowest

````
app_type          Bytes_received  Bytes_sent
------------------------------------------------
software updates  10098120398214  09832140914
email              89032409       9874398


SELECT
    app_type AS ['App Type'], 
    COUNT (*) AS ['Top App type'] 
FROM
    dbo.WirelessAppData
GROUP BY 
    app_type 
ORDER BY
    ['Top App type'] DESC;

Uncategorized App Type  143305
Tunnel                  123024
Media                    85947
Facebook                 66698
Search Engine            62031
Social Networking        50168
Internet Utilities       48973
Instant Messaging        40977
File Sharing             19595
Games                    13432
Internal                 12700
Business                  9333
iTunes                    9298
Microsoft                 8995
Webmail                   4644
Software Updates          3301

select app_type, bytes_received, bytes_sent 
from WirelessAppData 
where app_type = 'Software Updates' 
order by bytes_received desc;

Software Updates    465108871   551
Software Updates    460464329   930
Software Updates    460271605   864
Software Updates    374041259   941
Software Updates    354425776   950
Software Updates    344554876   823
Software Updates    297851528   772
Software Updates    289410332   933
Software Updates    267913740   989
```
````

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Hello Sorry.. I was hoping to get the return of   something like the first section

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, but it seems you might benefit from a `GROUP BY`. You need to [edit] your post to add more details as to what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select app_type, sum(bytes_received) as bytes_received ,sum(bytes_sent) as bytes_sent
from WirelessAppData
group by app_type
order by bytes_received desc
```